# Rails integration test: wrong number of arguments error when calling 'to_json'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, devise

I am working on a rails project where I want to support both direct web access as well as API accesses through JSON.

Currently, I am trying to get devise working with JSOn. However, during testing I run into an ArgumentError when I add ".json" to my URL:

```
post "/users/sign_in", user: { nick: 'testguy', password: 'password' }, "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json'
```

This will execute, but produces an HTML response.

```
post "/users/sign_in.json"
```

This executes as well, and produces JSON output (complaining that I need to sign in or sign up)

Now, this I would expect to work:

```
post "/users/sign_in.json", user: { nick: 'testguy', password: 'password' }, "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json'
```

But instead, I do get an execution error in that line:

```
 1) Error:
UserFlowsTest#test_simple_json_login:
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
    test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:54:in `block in <class:UserFlowsTest>'
```

My questions:

1) What happens when I add ".json" to an URI within a post call? I guess it somehow calls `.to_json()`, but why is it missing an argument, and where would I put it in my post call?

2) Or am I doing something completely wrong? Is there a better way to post JSON requests in a plain integration tests? (I didn't have issues with `get "/some_path.json"`btw)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Version information:

- rails 4.1.1
- devise 3.2.4

### Edit:

The whole test looks like this (haven't put in assertions yet, as I am still trying to understand the Error I get):

```
test "simple json login" do
  users(:testguy).confirm!
  post "/users/sign_in.json", user: { nick: 'testguy', password: 'password' }, "CONTENT_TYPE" => 'application/json'
  puts response.body
end
```

BTW, this test (HTTP login followed by JSON get) works fine:

```
test "basic json" do
  get new_user_session_path
  assert_response :success
  users(:testguy).confirm!
  post_via_redirect new_user_session_path, user: { nick: 'testguy', password: 'password' }
  assert_nil flash[:alert]
  assert_equal 'Signed in successfully.', flash[:notice]
  assert_equal '/discussions', path
  get "#{path}.json" #, type: :json
  assert_match /"id":\d+/, response.body
end
```

### Edit2:

I finally narrowed this down to be caused by a call to `render :json` (or rather, `respond_with resource` in Devise::SessionsController). I subclassed it and and as soon as I call `to_json` with some options it works:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render json: current_user.to_json(only: [:id, :authentication_token])
  }
  format.html {
    redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  }
```

If I do not explicitly call `to_json` with non-nil arguments, I get a "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Is this supposed to happen? Or is this a bug on my side or somewhere within the frameworks I am using?

Comment: In your testing framework, **nothing** happens when you add `.json` to the URI; it just posts to the URI you passed. So you're not posting JSON... you're posting standard form data (with invalid headers indicating you're posting JSON). Without seeing more code it's unclear whether that's the cause of the error you're getting, but knowing that should give you a jumping-off point.

Comment: Well, my assumption was that nothing happens. However, I do get the ArgumentError shown above, exactly for the line of code I am showing. If I simply remove the `.json` from that line, I do not get the Error...

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the same issue. What was the solution for you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post solution

Comment: Well, I didn't find a solution... In the end, I abandoned my little project and told myself not to rely on too many frameworks in future endeavors....